# jquery, binding order/wait for callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

I wrote a jquery plugin for validating forms. It bounds itself to the $('element').Submit event to trigger the validation (the bind is inside the plugin). Somehow like this:

```
// pseudocode
jquery.rdy {
       $('form').validate(); //binding the plugin
}
```

Inside of the validate plug I bind the validation to the submit

```
//pseudocode
[...]
$().submit(function () {
    validating... //returning true/false

    if (false) {
        return false //prevent submit form
    }
}
[...]
```

So and now my question is how can I bind (in other js scripts for example) other stuff to the submit but just if a validation is done.

so like this

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    if (validate plugin was executed) {
        //do stuff like check if validation was returning a true and now do something else
    }
}
```

Hopefully I descriped it right ...my english is not the best but I tryed to be as concrete s possible (and i hope, pseudocode is a right approach as well)

// EDIT: make the problem more concrete:
I'm trying to figure out a way to solve the following problem: (its very out of the context but the problem is exactly there..)
I have a submit event which is doing something depending on some code triggered in a another decleration.

```
$('element').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('foo')) {
        // do something
    }
});

$('element').submit(function () {
    $(this).addClass('foo');
});
```

And now the first function is doing nothing cause it has been triggered before the second one. Is there a clean way to solve this. Maybe I need a timeout event (even I hate them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind more functions to the form element with custom names.

```
$('form').bind('after_validation',function(){ console.log('hello'); });
```

And trigger them in your submit form function when you need it:

```
$('form').trigger('after_validation');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

---

***Update:***

You cannot change the order of your bound submit events without removing them `.unbind('submit')` and re-applying in the correct order. What you can do is use custom binds (see above) and trigger them exactly when you need it - like.. inside the submit function.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    //run validation
    $('form').trigger('validation');

    //did it pass validation?
    if($(this).data('invalid')){
        console.log('did not pass validation');
        return false;
    }

    //passed validation - submit the form
    return true;
});

//add validation to the "form"
$('form').bind('validation',function () {

    //do validation on form...

    if(false){
        $(this).data('invalid',true);
    }
});



//add another validator to the form, etc.
$('form').bind('validation',func...
```

Im using `.data()` to store variables to the 'form' element so you can access them down the chain.

This is the basis of what you need and can be applied to a custom jquery plugin to form custom named functions. eg. `$().validator()`.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: yes that would work but then i need do declare all my statements in this "after validation" function. and i dont want something like that (thought of the call function of js as well).
i want a normal submit event doing my stuff. but just i want to be sure this submit event is executed when some stuff is done (in my case my validation plug done his job). so i could do something like adding a "invalid" class to the form with my plug and check it in the second submit event like "if !hasclass(invalid)" but this if is always true because the form dont have invalid cause the plug is executed to late

Comment: not 100 % what i searched for but the best answer i could find and i could solve the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery.Validate (which it looks like you are with the .validate() syntax), you can just call the *isValid()* method:

```
if (validate plugin was executed) {
```

can then be

```
if ($('form').isValid()) {
```

Comment: yes i could do something like that to verify the form then with my plugin. but i dont wanna verify it there. because the form is getting verified anyway as it should by the trigger form.submit function inside of the plugin. but the point is ...the validation progress trough the plugin starts to late. simply -  i have two binds on the submit but i want to make sure the validate plug is first then afterwards the other is started. so i want to have a if inside of the second submit bind to lookup if the validation is done before. hmm hard to descripe in english but i hope u get me!